# Properties of a general element of the intersection of two Schubert cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians, schubert-calculus, schubert-varieties

We have the following lemma:

**Lemma**

Let $\Sigma_a(\mathcal{V}),\Sigma_b(\mathcal{W})$ be two Schubert cycles defined relative to transverse flags $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$. If $\Lambda \in \Sigma_a(\mathcal{V}) \cap \Sigma_b(\mathcal{W})$ is a general point of their intersection, then:

1. $\Lambda$ doesn't lie in any strictly smaller Schubert cycle $\Sigma_{a'}(\mathcal{V}) \subsetneq \Sigma_a(\mathcal{V})$.
2. The flags induced by $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ on $\Lambda$ are transverse.

By the first part of the Lemma it follows that the induced flags $\Lambda^{\mathcal{V}}$ and $\Lambda^{\mathcal{W}}$ are explicitly $\Lambda_i^{\mathcal{V}}=\Lambda \cap V_{n-k+i-a_i}$ and $\Lambda_i^{\mathcal{W}}=\Lambda \cap W_{n-k+i-b_i}$, for $i=1,\dots,k$.

The proof of the point $1$ is clear to me. As for the point $2$, there is a step is which not clear to me. Explicitly we have to show that for general $\Lambda$ in the intersection, we have $\Lambda \cap V_{n-k+i-a_i} \cap W_{n-i-b_{k-i}}=0$. For this purpose we consider the incidence correspondence
$$
\phi=\{(\Lambda,[v]) \in (\Sigma_a \cap \Sigma_b)\times \mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i}\cap V_{n-i-b_{k-i}})\; | v \in \Lambda\}
$$
This is a projective variety and if we show that $\mathrm{dim}(\phi) < \mathrm{dim}(\Sigma_a \cap \Sigma_b)$, then we are done, since the projection $\phi \to \Sigma_a \cap \Sigma_b$ cannot be dominant. Now it is said that

> By the first part of the lemma we can replace $\phi$ by the preimage of the complement $U$ of $\mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i-1} \cap W_{n-i-b_{k-i}}) \cup \mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i} \cap W_{n-i-b_{k-i}-1})$ in $\mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i}\cap W_{n-i-b_{k-i}})$.

I thought that maybe this is because the preimage of $U$ is an open dense subset of $\phi$, and hence this preimage must have the same dimension as $\phi$. But, if this is true I cannot see why this follows from the first point of the lemma. Moreover, if my assumption is not true, I cannot see why we can substitute $\phi$ by the preimage of $U$.

The lemma is taken from "3264 and all that" by Harris and Eisenbud (page 140).

Answer (score 1):

Define $\tilde{a}$ by $\widetilde{a_i} = a_i+1$. Define also $\widetilde{b}$ by $\widetilde{b_{k-i}} = b_{k-i}+1$.
Then it is clear that $\Sigma_{\widetilde{a}}$ is a strict Schubert sub-cycle of $\Sigma_a$ and $\Sigma_{\widetilde{b}}$ is a strict Schubert sub-cycle of $\Sigma_b$.

By the first part of the lemma, we know that $\Sigma_{\widetilde{a}} \cap \Sigma_b$ and $\Sigma_{a} \cap \Sigma_{\widetilde{b}}$ are strict subvarieties of $\Sigma_{a} \cap \Sigma_b$.

But the preimage of
$$\mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i-1}) \cap \mathbb{P}(W_{n-i-b_{k-i}}) \cup \mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i}) \cap \mathbb{P}(W_{n-i-b_{k-i}-1})$$
in $\phi$ maps to $\Sigma_{\widetilde{a}} \cap \Sigma_b \cup \Sigma_{a} \cap \Sigma_{\widetilde{b}}$. Hence, it doesn't matter that you withdraw this subset in $\phi$ to check that the map $\phi \rightarrow \Sigma_a \cap \Sigma_b$ is dominant or not.

Comment: Why does the preimage of
$$\mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i-1}) \cap \mathbb{P}(W_{n-i-b_{k-i}}) \cup \mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_i}) \cap \mathbb{P}(W_{n-i-b_{k-i}-1})$$
in $\phi$ maps to $\Sigma_{\widetilde{a}} \cap \Sigma_b \cup \Sigma_{a} \cap \Sigma_{\widetilde{b}}$? To be more precise: let $[v] \in \mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_{i-1}}) \cap \mathbb{P}(V_{n-i-b_{k-i}})$, why does the preimage of this element consist of couples $(\Lambda, [v])$ with $\Lambda \in \Sigma_{\tilde{a}} \cap \Sigma_b$?

Comment: This is by definition of transverse flags and the definition of Schubert cycles!

Comment: But I know for sure that $\Lambda$ belongs to $\Sigma_a \cap \Sigma_b$. Why does this must lie in $\Sigma_{\tilde{a}}\cap \Sigma_b$? If i take an element $[v] \in \mathbb{P}(V_{n-k+i-a_{i-1}})\cap \mathbb{P}(V_{n-i-b_{k-i}})$ it could be that an element of the fibre $\Lambda$ may lie in $\Sigma_a \setminus \Sigma_{\tilde{a}}$. Why does this cannot happen? Thank you for your help Libli.